# retrieve another image in database SQLite Android

Tags: android, image

i'm new here :D

i have retrieve an image in database sqlite in my android app, but when i try to get another image, the image still just same like before. it always retrive image from row 1, i don't know why

this is my code

```
public void findAlphabet(View view) {
    try {
        db = kamusTI.getWritableDatabase();
        String sql = "SELECT * FROM kamusti WHERE istilah LIKE '"
                + editAlphabet.getText().toString() + "%' ORDER BY istilah";
        cursor = db.rawQuery(sql, null);            
        adapter2 = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_2, cursor, new String[] {
                        "istilah", "definisi" }, new int[] {
                        android.R.id.text1, android.R.id.text2 });
        listView2.setAdapter(adapter2);
        listView2.setTextFilterEnabled(true);
        String sql1 = "SELECT COUNT(istilah) FROM kamusti WHERE istilah LIKE '"
                + editAlphabet.getText().toString() + "%' ORDER BY istilah";
        cursor = db.rawQuery(sql1, null);
        cursor.moveToFirst();

        cur = db.query("kamusti", null, null, null, null, null, null);
        cur.moveToFirst();
    //  cur.moveToPosition(0);
        byte[] im = cur.getBlob(3);
        //  ByteArrayInputStream imagestream = new ByteArrayInputStream(im);
            Bitmap imagestream = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(im, 0, im.length);
        //  Bitmap image = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(imagestream);
            img = (ImageView) findViewById (R.id.gambar);
            img.setImageBitmap(imagestream); 
        hasilCari.setText("Hasil Pencarian : " + cursor.getInt(0));
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        hasilCari.setText(e.toString());
    }
}
```

i just don't have any idea how to fix this. when i try to find another alphabet in my app, the image will appear is always in row 1 in database.
please help me :)

*sorry for my bad english

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh, man, I am sorry but I must say it: your code is really awful...

It is not organised at all, but maybe... shouldn't `byte[] im = cur.getBlob(3);` be `byte[] im = cursor.getBlob(3);` instead?

**EDIT**: try to comment the second and third queries, since they seem useless, and make the "cur" -> "cursor" change I suggested:

```
    public void findAlphabet(View view) {
        try {
            db = kamusTI.getWritableDatabase();
            String sql = "SELECT * FROM kamusti WHERE istilah LIKE '"
                    + editAlphabet.getText().toString() + "%' ORDER BY istilah";
            cursor = db.rawQuery(sql, null);            
            adapter2 = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,
                    android.R.layout.simple_list_item_2, cursor, new String[] {
                            "istilah", "definisi" }, new int[] {
                            android.R.id.text1, android.R.id.text2 });
            listView2.setAdapter(adapter2);
            listView2.setTextFilterEnabled(true);
//            String sql1 = "SELECT COUNT(istilah) FROM kamusti WHERE istilah LIKE '"
//                    + editAlphabet.getText().toString() + "%' ORDER BY istilah";
//            cursor = db.rawQuery(sql1, null);
              cursor.moveToFirst();

//            cur = db.query("kamusti", null, null, null, null, null, null);
//            cur.moveToFirst();
        //  cur.moveToPosition(0);
            byte[] im = cursor.getBlob(3);
            //  ByteArrayInputStream imagestream = new ByteArrayInputStream(im);
                Bitmap imagestream = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(im, 0, im.length);
            //  Bitmap image = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(imagestream);
                img = (ImageView) findViewById (R.id.gambar);
                img.setImageBitmap(imagestream); 
            hasilCari.setText("Hasil Pencarian : " + cursor.getInt(0));
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            hasilCari.setText(e.toString());
        }
    }
```

Comment: i've try it, but the app was force close when i click search button :(

Comment: Then you should edit your original post and copy/paste LogCat exception if you want us to help you. On the other hand, you should improve your code... why do you need 3 queries? It seems like your first query is what you need, but what about the other two? BTW, you should explain things better, I assume that your findAlphabet method is the onClick handler of a button defined in an XML layout, isn't it? You never said that, but you assume we already know...

Comment: i have try using your code that you suggested.
the image have displayed in my app, but it still displaying an image in row 1 from database
i try to search another image in my database but still displaying image in row 1
i'm really confused, 

anyway thanks for your help before

Comment: does anyone have a clue? i really want to finish my app :(

Comment: Let's see, I am not really sure you understand your own code... `cursor.moveToFirst();` selects the first row of the selecting query results, and `cursor.getBlob(3);` selects the third column of that row. Maybe the problem is just your query, and is always returning the first row of your database for some reason. Are you sure that the generated SQL query is correct? We don't know how your database is, so we couldn't help you.

Comment: i'm sorry, i have try to another laptop and voila!!
another image have displayed using your syntax
thankyou so much man, now i can continued my project :D

thanksss

Comment: You're welcome! Maybe you should tick my answer as correct then:-)

Comment: if you don't mind, can i ask you more? :D
because when i search data in database but in case that data is not available, the app is force close. how to catch the error or make a toast to display if the data in database is not found

Comment: You should always check if a query returns rows or not. Just proceed if there are > 0 returned rows.